# Viewing latex file and pdf file in split screen mode

Tags: split, screen

I want to have both latex source code on left half of screen and compiled pdf file on right side of screen.  How can I do ths

Comment: Welcome! Many editors allow this by default, check Texmaker, TexStudio, as examples, too many others do.

Comment: Depending on the tex system you may already have that ability For example basic versions of MiKTeX windows, ProTeX windows and TexLive windows all include such an editor MiKTeX and Tex Live use a simple TeXworks ProTeX includes MiKTeX but adds TeXstudio

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at texstudio if you're beginning. I found it to be the best of texstudio, texmaker and kile for learning and quite user friendly. As you progress